# Highchart angular directive doesn't redraw from dynamic (ajax) data table

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, highcharts

I have an AngularJs app that retrieves data from API and populates them into table. Then, I'm using Highcharts to draw chart based on that table. It is working fine if I'm using static data in the table, but it doesn't work when I update the table through AJAX. It doesn't get redraw.

Directive:

```
app.directive('highChart', function ($parse) {
    return {        
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('chartConfig', function (newVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    var props = $parse(attrs.highChart)(scope);
                    props.chart.renderTo = element[0];
                    new Highcharts.Chart(props);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
appControllers.controller('SummaryController', ['$scope', '$timeout', 'Summaries',
    function ($scope, $timeout, Summaries) {
        // Request from API
        Summaries.get({ table: 'level'}).$promise.then(
            // success callback
            function(data) {
                $scope.levels = data.level[0][today];
                $scope.chartConfig = {
                    data: {
                        table: document.getElementById('daily-level')
                    },
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        allowDecimals: false,
                        title: {
                            text: 'Units'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                                this.y + ' ' + this.x;
                        }
                    }
                 };
            }
    }]);
```

HTML

```
<div id="top-chart" high-chart="chartConfig"></div>
```

It just displays an empty chart. My table does get updated by the AJAX request. I even did check for `console.log(props)` inside the directive and `props.data.table` does show the updated table, but somehow the chart doesn't get redraw. I've tried multiple ways to do this, but all come down to the same result. Currently, I'm just using jQuery timeout to refresh the chart, it works but that means I'm using DOM manipulation inside controller. I'm trying to achieve this using directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I managed to get it to work. I think the problem is that, Highcharts does not aware about the changes or if it knows about the changes, the DOM at that moment hasn't finish rendering. This is the working version of the code.

Directive:

```
app.directive('highchart', function($parse, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div></div>',
        replace: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var config = $parse(attrs.config)(scope);
            $(element[0]).highcharts(config);

            scope.$watch(attrs.watch, function(newVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    var complete = function (options) {
                        var chart = $(element[0]).highcharts();
                        // capture all available series
                        var allSeries = chart.series;
                        for (var i = 0; i < allSeries.length; i++) {
                            allSeries[i].setData(options.series[i].data, false);
                        }

                        chart.redraw();
                    };

                    // doesn't work without the timeout 
                    $timeout(function() {
                        Highcharts.data({
                            table: config.data.table,
                            complete: complete
                        });   
                    }, 0);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In controller, we can setup the config.

```
    $scope.chartConfig = {
         // config here
    };
```

To use it:

```
<highchart config="chartConfig" watch="levels"></highchart>
```

where the attribute `config` is bind to the `$scope.chartConfig` and `watch` is the trigger for `watch.$scope()` in the directive. When `$scope.levels` changes in controller, it would re-render the chart.

I don't actually like the dependency of the directive to the `watch` attribute that I have right now, but I'm not sure what is the best or other way to do this. If anyone have a better idea, do let me know.

Please note that this will only work to convert table to highchart. For others, you might need to use other angularjs highcharts directive.

Answer (score 1):

In given below example, you can update your graph as per updated data in database using watch.It keeps on checking for new data and makes changes respectively:

```
app.directive('line',['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div></div>',
        scope: {
            data: '=',
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.lineGraphInstance = Highcharts.chart(element[0],{
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline',
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '8px'
                    },
                    spacingBottom: scope.data.spacingBottom,
                    spacingTop: scope.data.spacingTop,
                    spacingLeft: scope.data.spacingLeft,
                    spacingRight: scope.data.spacingRight,
                },
                title: {
                    text: '',
                },                      
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    title: {
                        text: scope.data.xtitle,
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '8px'
                        },                  
                        autoRotation: 0,
                        formatter: function () {
                            var x=this.value;
                            if (scope.data.hasOwnProperty("dateformat"))
                                x= Highcharts.dateFormat(scope.data.dateformat, this.value);
                            if (scope.data.hasOwnProperty("xSuffix"))
                                x=x+scope.data.xSuffix;         
                            if(scope.data.hasOwnProperty("xPrefix"))
                                x=scope.data.xPrefix+x;

                            return x;
                        },
                    enabled:scope.data.xtitleEnable
                    },
                    tickWidth: 3,
                    tickLength:scope.data.tickLength,
                    tickInterval: 3600 * 100
                        },
                yAxis: {
                    opposite: true,
                    title: {
                        text: scope.data.ytitle,
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '10px'
                        },
                        formatter: function () {
                            var y=this.value;
                            if (scope.data.hasOwnProperty("ySuffix"))
                                y=y+scope.data.ySuffix;         
                            if(scope.data.hasOwnProperty("yPrefix"))
                                y=scope.data.yPrefix+y;

                            return y;
                        },
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: scope.data.ucl,
                        color: '#F39C12',
                        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                        width: 1,
                    }, {
                        value: scope.data.lcl,
                        color: '#F39C12',
                        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                        width: 1,
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
                    pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} '
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    spline: {
                        marker: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend:{
                    enabled:false
                },
                series:[{data:scope.data.data,
                marker: {
                    enabled: true,
                    radius: 2
                },
                lineWidth: 1
                }],
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },  
                exporting: { enabled: false 
                }
            }); 
            ***scope.$watch('data', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if(newValue && newValue.data){
                    var graphData=newValue.data[0].data.slice(-5);
                    scope.lineGraphInstance.series[0].setData(graphData, true);
                }
            }, true);
        }***
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set factory, which will use `$resource` http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource inside and then iniliatize chart after calling getting values from factory?

EDIT: updated example http://jsfiddle.net/csTzc/184/

Comment: Yes, `Summaries` are actually the factory.

Comment: See my edit post, where I placed example, probably the prolbem was with data.js

Comment: It works, but if I generate the table dynamically through AJAX, it doesn't work anymore. That is my initial problem. I'll try to create some example to show it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/67nm6/2/ Take a look at this. It doesn't work if I generate the table dynamically.