# Automatically redraw a highStock chart under Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, highcharts

I want to make a highStock chart under AngularJS, and I want to change some chart option by some buttons. However, it seems that changing the option does not redraw the chart automatically. I tried to follow [a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20698591/702977) which works with highChart, but I cannot make the directive work with highStock. Here is [a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/tmoA2VccKugiN7JxjdHb?p=preview), the watch is well triggered, whereas I don't know how redraw the chart well.

```
  .directive('highchart', function($parse, $timeout) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div></div>',
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var config = $parse(attrs.config)(scope);
        Highcharts.stockChart(element[0], config);

        scope.$watch(attrs.watch, function(newVal) {
          if (newVal) {
            console.log("here" + JSON.stringify(newVal))
            $timeout(function() {
              Highcharts.stockChart(element[0], config);
            }, 0);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  })
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: I am not familiar with HighCharts, but one thing you can check if this is this the correct way to redraw the HighCharts? Besides, I am not able to see any change in the configs of first time and that in the watcher.

Comment: Looks like this not related to Angular but really to HighCharts. I tried modifying it and here is my modifications: https://plnkr.co/edit/VubMRQUBJXqpaHmnPq4f   Try to have a look at config changing with respect to new selections and clearing your chart before redrawing it.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880978/highcharts-jquery-destroy-and-rebuild-chart-with-original-options

Comment: @SoftTimur I added working https://plnkr.co/edit/VWnYvI832iBdMdZBMruP?p=preview. Now what you want to do please explain.

Comment: Looking at Patata's working solution, it is very clear that your chart `config` is not getting updated with `newVal` at appropriate options.

Answer (score 0):

For updating already rendered chart you need to use **functions** from this section of the API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/classes.list (`Chart.update()`, `Series.addPoint()` etc.).

**Your example with `update` function**: https://plnkr.co/edit/X1LnekXUX0WrodQFCqMp?p=preview

```
    $scope.chooseUnit = function (unit) {
      $scope.chart.series[0].update({
        dataGrouping: {
          units: [[unit.name, [1]]]
        }
      });
      $scope.unitSelected = unit
    }
```

Comment: I finally used [highcarhts-ng](https://rawgithub.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/master/src/highcharts-ng.js) which works so far. I have not got a chance to test your solution... Thank you...